# How restrict public access to S3 Bucket in AWS SAM Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am currently trying to define an s3 bucket for a cloud formation deployment using the SAM template. Following the documentation I thought I was setting the PublicAccessBlockConfiguration correctly:

```
(yaml)
    S3Bucket1:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          BucketName: abl-ar-report-container 
          BucketEncryption: 
            ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration: 
            - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                SSEAlgorithm: AES256
          PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
            BlockPublicAcls : true
            BlockPublicPolicy : true
            IgnorePublicAcls : true
            RestrictPublicBuckets : true
```

however when I deploy I get the following message:

Resource with id [S3Bucket1] is invalid. property PublicAccessBlockConfiguration not defined for resource of type AWS::S3::Bucket

I did see some references to template variations on git 
I am declaring the AWS template as:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: A template for a Node.js-based application 

Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
```

After further digging I think I am mixing CF template syntax with SAM syntax. Can anyone point me to the correct documentation or syntax for these settings?

Comment: Is this a CFN template or a SAM template? It seems to be incomplete. Does it validate?

Comment: This is a snippet from SAM template. This is the full definition for the s3 bucket. If I remove the PubicAccessBlockConfiguration section it will deploy the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dug into this a bit and it is currently a bug in SAM. Here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/679). There is a [patch](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/pull/700) that has been merged and it should be fixed in v1.10.0.

The root of the problem is that the s3 model in SAM has a hard-coded list of properties, and `PublicAccessBlockConfiguration` is relatively new and had not been added yet.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create s3bucket with default settings . S3 by default is blocked for public access. And simply associate IAM role/policy to reads3 objects for CFN depoloyment

Comment: I had no problem creating bucket with this template